# if construction don't work in python 2.4, but work in python 2.7.13

Tags: python

```
def make_single(op,size,end,sign):
name = '_%s%s%s%s' % (op, size, end, sign)
fmt  = sizes[size]
end = '>' if end == 'b' else '<'
```

this construction work great in python on my local machine with python 2.7.13
But on remote machine with python 2.4 i get a syntax error

```
    sh-3.2$ python test.py
      File "test.py", line 195
        end = '>' if end == 'b' else '<'
                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

whats wrong ?

Comment: Please format your code properly

Answer (score 2):

Well, indeed that construct is not valid in Python 2.4, as it was introduced in Python 2.5. But why would you use 2.4 anyway, a version that was released in 2004 and which has not been supported since 2008?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply not supported on Python 2.4 (was added on 2.5). See [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html).